# In polymer, how do you CSS select the first element of the host's parent?

Tags: polymer

Lets say I have a polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="milo-item" attributes="item" noscript>   <template>
    <style>
      host:first-child {
        color: red;
      }
      host(:first-child) {
        color: red;
      }
      host(:first-child) paper-item::shadow .button-content {
        color: red;
      }
      paper-item::shadow .button-content {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-item>
      ...
    </paper-item>

  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

(I added extra CSS selectors to indicate what doesn't work)

And then I create a bunch of the elements under a div:

```
<template repeat="{{item in foo}}">
  <milo-item item="{{item}}">
</template>
```

How do I get a CSS selector to apply to just the first item of the parent of the host?

I would expect :host(:first-child) to work, but it doesn't

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The title says, "The first element of host's parent" and the description says, "the first item of the host." 

:host is the host element -- in this case, `<milo-item>`. Are you trying to select its first child, the first child inside its shadow root (the paper-item), or the first `<milo-item>` in a list of `<milo-item>`s?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you need the colon in front of `:host`.

`:host(:first-child)` selects the host element itself **if the host element is the first child of its own parent.**. The selector inside the parens qualifies the *host element*. For example, `:host(.foo)` selects `<milo-item class="foo">`. If you want to style the first milo-item in your list, go no farther. (Except maybe to change it to `:first-of-type`.)

`:host :first-child` should match the first *child* in the host's shadow tree. However, it matches *any* first children in your shadow root, so you probably want `:host > :first-child` instead, to just match the first top-level child. Because first child can be a little weird (for example, if there are invisible elements in there you weren't thinking about) it may be safer to use `:first-of-type` or `:nth-of-type`

So the final answer to how you style the first `<paper-item>` *inside* your `<milo-item>`'s shadow DOM (a.k.a. local DOM) is:

`:host > paper-item:first-of-type`

By the way, if you ACTUALLY want to style `<milo-item>`'s first child -- that is, an actual child in the light DOM -- you first need to add an insertion point so it gets rendered, and select it like this:

`:host ::content :first-child`

Here's a jsbin showing these rules in action:

http://jsbin.com/kuqobi/4/edit?html,console,output

Hope this helps.

Comment: My colleague points out that `:nth-of-type` is a lot more predictable. For example, `paper-item:nth-of-type(1)` would ignore the `<style>` tag and select the first `<paper-item>`. See: http://robdodson.me/nth-child-is-weird/

Comment: Edited answer to update code to Polymer 1.0, and correct some errors in my original answer.